# Host two domains on one VPS - 2nd domain not working

Tags: apache, dns, hosting, vps

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/joshhornby
ServerName joshhornby.com
ServerAlias www.joshhornby.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/designerschool
ServerName designer-school.com
ServerAlias www.designer-school.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to run two domains from one vps server

This is my set up in the httpd.config file. When I load joshhornby.co.uk it works as expected. I have placed a index.html file in designerschool and when I type the URL in it doesn't load. I have done `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 0):

After doing a looking at your A records for both www.joshhornby.co.uk and www.designer-school.com, they don't see to be pointing to the same place. Make sure the A records for www.designer-school.com are pointing to the same place (`141.101.116.48`) as joshhornby.co.uk and you should be good.

Also your config can look like this (as per [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/joshhornby
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/designerschool
ServerAlias www.designer-school.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That IP address is one of CloudFlares so I can't use it, I just tried using my IP address for joshhornby.co.uk and this ended up making designer-school go to joshhornby.co.uk and display that site. What seems to have happened is designer-school.com is now pointing and displaying joshhornby.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with keeping the "ServerAlias" entry.  Is joshhornby.co.uk and designer-school.com both pointing to same host? Because they are pointing to different ip addresses. If they are, then try this:

```
Server configuration

Listen 80

# This is the "main" server running on 172.20.30.40
ServerName server.domain.com
DocumentRoot /www/mainserver

# This is the other address
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.50

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

picked from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#twoips)